# Pandas / Sqlalchemy `NaT` coercion?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble with a bulk insert on a `datetime64[ns]` column with `NaT` values,

I am doing,

```
session.bulk_insert_mappings(SamExtract, df[:1000].to_dict(orient="records"))
```

It throws,

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NaT"
LINE 1: ... 'NaN'::float, false, false, false, false, false, 'NaT'::tim...
```

and then,

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NaT"
LINE 1: ... 'NaN'::float, false, false, false, false, false, 'NaT'::tim...
```

Comment: can the timestamp column in your db have nulls?

Comment: `nullable` defaults to `True`, https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.nullable

Comment: can you just replace the `NaT` with `None` since your database does not recognize that, and are you saying you put a not null constraint on that column?